# Unable to access the server via SSH?

Tags: server, ssh, login, log, logging

when I am trying to access the server through ssh it says:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.yyy.zzz.x port 22: Connection refused
```

and on the server in `auth.log` it shows following log entry:

```
Address xx.yyy.zzz.x maps to xx.yyy.zzz.x.static-pune-vsnl.net.in, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

I have created a user account for that user and it is also in enabled status.

### Requested info

1. It is Ubuntu 11.10
2. It is configured as SSH Server using openssh-server
3. I am trying to connect to this server using Putty from Windows 7 i.e. My Desktop
4. I have also asked this in superuser as per the request of @zpletan and link to that question is given below.

https://superuser.com/questions/408080/unable-to-access-the-server-via-ssh

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question, but do you have the `openssh-server` package installed on your server? Is your server running Ubuntu? (If not, the proper place to ask this is probably http://superuser.com.) Is it a web server or an internal server? Have you tried deleting ~/.ssh on the computer you're connecting from?

Comment: @zpletan Please check the updated quesion details. Thanks for your interest and have given you 1 up for the comment.

Comment: tray open your port 22 in your ufw -> `sudo ufw allow 22` or `sudo ufw allow ssh` info -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW and try to connect again...

Comment: @hhlp Thanks a lot buddy but still it is not working?? :(

Comment: @zpletan If you tell users to ask somewhere else then please mention the process of migration or tell them not to cross post.

Comment: @slhck, I suggested SU as an alternative to this site if the server was not running Ubuntu, not as an additional place to ask the question. I was not expecting the cross-post. Also, I don't know how to migrate posts, and according to meta (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1496/what-do-i-need-for-being-able-to-migrate-questions-to-other-stackexchange-sites) I'm not able to do so. If I knew how to migrate posts, I would have explained how.

Comment: @Rishee, cross-posting is a tricky thing, apparently. How about taking a look at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites and acting accordingly. If you decide to close one version of your question, I would probably close this one, as your problem seems to extend beyond Ubuntu.

Comment: @zpletan Fair enough! It's just a reminder that if you do "community moderation", be familiar with the process and etiquette behind it, that is: not sending new users somewhere else without explaining the process. Just a reminder, no offense :) I'd also say this question should be closed here.

Comment: What address are you using to connect to the server.. an internal IP (i.e. like 192.168.0.2 or 10.0.0.2), the WAN IP of local network (and then using a router/firewall to route the request to the server) (i.e. 86.10.117.176 or similar) or a domain name (like myserver.no-ip.info)?

Comment: @zpletan Will try my level best to stick to those rules but some of those rules I quite really could not understand. So please feel free to correct and let me know. Thank you buddy! for letting me know about it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server may enables `UseDNS`.

`man sshd_config` to find information about this.

If you have the right permission, you can modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `UseDNS no` to this file.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  This is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ISP has screwed up their DNS records.  ssh appears to be complaining because when it looks up the IP address xx.yyy.zzz.x, it gets the name xx.yyy.zzz.x.static-pune-vsnl.net, but that name does not map back to the IP address, which often is an indicator that someone is trying to spoof their hostname.  You should complain to your ISP to fix it, or change the setting fossilet mentioned.  Such screwed up DNS records will also prevent you from connecting to most IRC servers.

Comment: This should only be a problem if your routing the request through the outside world though right?  If your on an LAN and connecting to using the LAN IP of the server, why would sshd check the reverse DNS entry?

Comment: @Ashimema, because it doesn't differentiate between the two; IP is IP, whether it is 3 feet away or the other side of the world.  If this is supposed to be a local connection though, you have something messed up somewhere because it shouldn't see the connection coming from your public IP address.